# Find certain text in PDF, then return page number found on to another section NOTE: Uses Docotic.pdf

Tags: c#, .net

In the following code, the user will input a search string (barcodedata).  That string will then be truncated to the first 5 characters, and used as the jobnumber.  The jobnumber, is also the name of the pdf I will be scanning for the barcodedata.

What I would like, is for the 'Find it' button to execute the below code, then return the value found to startpagedata.

I can't tell if the program just isn't actually scanning the PDF for the search string, or if the value simply isn't returning to the program.

```
using BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Acrobat;

namespace BarCodeReader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string stringsToFind;
        public string pathtofile;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void barcodedata_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stringsToFind=barcodedata.Text;
            pathtofile = "C:\\" + StringTool.Truncate(barcodedata.Text, 5) + ".pdf";
            jobnumberdata.Text = StringTool.Truncate(barcodedata.Text, 5);
        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void jobnumberdata_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            jobnumberdata.Text = jobnumberdata.Text.TrimStart('0');
            Console.WriteLine(jobnumberdata.Text);
        }

        private void startpagedata_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(startpagedata.Text);
        }

        private void piecesdata_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void FindIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pathtofile);
            for (int i = 0; i < pdf.Pages.Count; i++)
            {
                string pageText = pdf.Pages[i].GetText();
                int count = 0;
                int lastStartIndex = pageText.IndexOf(stringsToFind, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                while (lastStartIndex != -1)
                {
                    count++;
                    lastStartIndex = pageText.IndexOf(stringsToFind, lastStartIndex + 1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                }

                if (count != 0)
                    startpagedata.Text = Convert.ToString(lastStartIndex);
            }

        }
    }

    public static class StringTool
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get a substring of the first N characters.
        /// </summary>
        public static string Truncate(string source, int length)
        {
            if (source.Length > length)
            {
                source = source.Substring(0, length);
            }
            return source;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a substring of the first N characters. [Slow]
        /// </summary>
        public static string Truncate2(string source, int length)
        {
            return source.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, source.Length));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your problem with this code? If FindIt_Click is not executed on click then probably you don't associate it with the "Find it" button.

The code in FindIt_Click looks quite correct except several things:

- It may not do what you expect. It returns *the last index in the text of the last page where the search string was found*. But may be you expect *the index of the last page where the search string was found*?
- You may use [pageText.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224420.aspx) method to quickly find *lastStartIndex*.
- Don't forget to Dispose PdfDocument instance. E.g. use *using* keyword:

```
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pathtofile))
    {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: When I click on 'Find it', the program runs, then displays the 'You are using the trial version...' dialog, but never actually displays anything other than that (when I pull that part of the code out and run it as a console app).  The Trial restrictions state that only the first half of the pdf will be scanned, so I've grabbed my search string from the first half of the pages to be safe.

I was hoping to export the actual page number where the search string is found.  Am I going about this in the correct way?

Comment: All of this sounds good. You can receive a temporary license key in order to test Docotic.Pdf in fully functional mode (and avoid limitations). I suggest to move this discussion to Docotic.Pdf support.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Docotic.pdf` you can use `Acrobat.dll` to find the current page number. First of all open the pdf file and search the string using

```
Acroavdoc.open("Filepath","Temperory title")
```

and

```
Acroavdoc.FindText("String").
```

If the string found in this pdf file then the cursor moved into the particular page and the searched string will be highlighted. Now we use `Acroavpageview.GetPageNum()` to get the current page number.

```
Dim AcroXAVDoc As CAcroAVDoc
Dim Acroavpage As AcroAVPageView
Dim AcroXApp As CAcroApp

AcroXAVDoc = CType(CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc"), Acrobat.CAcroAVDoc)
AcroXApp = CType(CreateObject("AcroExch.App"), Acrobat.CAcroApp)

AcroXAVDoc.Open("File path", "Original document")
AcroXAVDoc.FindText("String is to searched", True, True, False)

Acroavpage = AcroXAVDoc.GetAVPageView()

Dim x As Integer = Acroavpage.GetPageNum
MsgBox("the string found in page number" & x)
```